# Roberts kaufman formula in Python code to java

Tags: java, python, algorithm

I am working on Kaufman-Roberts Formula for full-availability systems, and im not conversant with python and i want to translate a piece of code into java, so it can help me in my research on kaufman formula.

```
import numpy as np

def Krauff_rec (V,M,A,T,x, sigma):
   x=[1]
   summ=float(0)
   MinT=[] 
   for i in range(1,v=1):
    ii=0
    for j in T:
        if (j<=i):
            #print (i,"j=  " j, "x=",x)
            summ+=A[ii]*j*x[i-j]*sigma[ii][i-j]

        ii+=1
    x.append(summ/(i))
    summ=0
 x=np.asarray(x) 
 summ=np.sum(x)

 p=[i/summ for i x]
     E=[]

     summ=0
     for i in range (M)
       for j in reange (k*(f-f-T[i]+1),v+1):
         summ+=1-sigma[i][j]

         E.append(summ)
         summ=0
         print(x)
         return[p,E]

         M=int(input("Enter number of class M="))
         k=int(input("Enter number of link k="))
         f=int(input("Enter the capasity per link f="))

         v=k*f
         x=np.asarray(x)
         summ=np.sum(x)
         p=[i/summ for i in x]
         E=[]
         summ=0
         for i in range (M): 
             for j in range(V-T[i]+1,V+1):
                 summ+=P[j]
                 E.append(summ)
                 summ=0
f = open("Results.txt", "W")
f.write("A[i] = "+np.array2string(A))
f.write("\nP[n] = "+str(P))
f.write("\nE[i] = "+str(E))
f.close()
```

Could anyone help me  with this conversion to java thank you.

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: only issue is i have no clue how to convert the above code to java, i am required to this in java

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted only a few of pieces are Python-specific:

- `range()` function - it's a kind of fancy replacement of traditional `for` loop in Java. E.g. instead of `for(int i=0; i < n; i++)` in Python we can write `for i in range(0, n)`. You can find more information in [documentation for built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range).
- `p=[i/summ for i x]` - it's a generator. Quite specific concept without direct equivalent in Java. You can explore generators on [Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).
- Some functions from [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) package are used. Their's names are self-explanatory. But again, just search the docs.

As for [the formula](https://books.google.by/books?id=4rxWS-5OJ60C&pg=PT128&lpg=PT128&dq=Roberts+kaufman+formula&source=bl&ots=hcU77BpK9q&sig=ACfU3U3dS-6wwt7g0ZkQyh1y90SlkHupiw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVpund8a7qAhVoSBUIHbzHDWsQ6AEwD3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Roberts%20kaufman%20formula&f=false), it's not an easy pickings. So it will be better to ask a theoretical question on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/). You will be able to implement the formula from scratch in Java rather than understand someone's Python code which is not guaranteed to be correct.